# grep on stderr on bash while still writing stdout to logfile

Tags: bash, redirect, grep, stderr

In a cronjob, my program called "prog" writes all stdout-information to the Logfile. All ERROR messages should be on stderr (like now) and are mailed because of the cronjob.

prog  >>/var/log/logfile

I would like to get all errors on STDERR except one special message, which should be excluded on stderr like
   grep -v "known error"

while still logging stdout to logfile.
How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best case here is to write a wrapper script that has the error exclusion logic built into it.  The wrapper script could filter out the ignorable errors and exit non-zero based on that.

In general, it is not great to rely on email sent by cron.  All errors should be internally handled and cronjob shouldn't produce any output.